# Nokogiri next_element with filter

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, beautifulsoup

Let's say I've got an ill formed html page:

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <th class="what_I_need">Super sweet text<th>
 </thead>
 <tr>
  <td>
    I also need this
  </td>
  <td>
    and this (all td's in this and subsequent tr's)
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   ...all td's here too
 </tr>
 <tr>
   ...all td's here too
 </tr>
</table>
```

On BeautifulSoup, we were able to get the `<th>` and then call `findNext("td")`.  Nokogiri has the `next_element` call, but that might not return what I want (in this case, it would return the `tr` element).

Is there a way to filter the `next_element` call of Nokogiri? e.g. `next_element("td")`?

**EDIT**

For clarification, I'll be looking at many sites, most of them ill formed in different ways.

For instance, the next site might be:

```
<table>
 <th class="what_I_need">Super sweet text<th>
 <tr>
  <td>
    I also need this
  </td>
  <td>
    and this (all td's in this and subsequent tr's)
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   ...all td's here too
 </tr>
 <tr>
   ...all td's here too
 </tr>
</table>
```

I can't assume any structure other than there will be `tr`s below the item that has the class `what_I_need`

Answer (score 2):

First, note that your closing `th` tag is malformed: `<th>`. It should be `</th>`. Fixing that helps.

One way to do it is to use XPath to navigate to it once you've found the `th` node:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '
<table>
<thead>
  <th class="what_I_need">Super sweet text<th>
</thead>
<tr>
  <td>
    I also need this
  </td>
<tr>
</table>
'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

th = doc.at('th.what_I_need')
th.text # => "Super sweet text"
td = th.at('../../tr/td')
td.text # => "\n    I also need this\n  "
```

This is taking advantage of Nokogiri's ability to use either CSS accessors or XPath, and to do it pretty transparently.

Once you have the `<th>` node, you could also navigate using some of Node's methods:

```
th.parent.next_element.at('td').text # => "\n    I also need this\n  "
```

One more way to go about it, is to start at the top of the table and look down:

```
table = doc.at('table')
th = table.at('th')
th.text # => "Super sweet text"
td = table.at('td')
td.text # => "\n    I also need this\n  "
```

If you need to access all `<td>` tags within a table you can iterate over them easily:

```
table.search('td').each do |td|
  # do something with the td...
  puts td.text
end
```

If you want the contents of all `<td>` by their containing `<tr>` iterate over the rows then the cells:

```
table.search('tr').each do |tr|
  cells = tr.search('td').map(&:text)
  # do something with all the cells
end
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  My initial question wasn't clear on the fact that I won't be certain of the structure of the page beyond a `table` with `tr`s. I've updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: It's important to be clear. There are many different ways to get where you want to be. If you don't know in advance what the page's layout is, you can write several different attempts and then run each one and see which returns a value for your `<td>` lookup. If you get a value you are good to go. If you don't try another.

Comment: I was hoping to find a more "generic" search option. I was hoping the just be able to say, I found the marker I'm looking for, now return all `<tr>`s that come after that marker.  Maybe this isn't possible and I need to just write a search function for every type of page I encounter? I've never done scraping before, so I was probably being naive

Comment: Do you want all `<tr>` tags, or the first `<td>`? Your question and your comment don't make that clear.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion again.  I want all the `<tr>` tags (I will be pulling info from the `<td>` tags, but once I have the `<tr>`, I know how to do that).  Question updated.